# Do objects in C/C++ get garbage collected after the program exits?

Tags: c++, c, garbage-collection

In C, and C++, assuming that I'm not using smart pointers or any other weird garbage collecting mechanism, does memory get deallocated (garbage collected) when the program exits?

Comment: It's not garbage collection.  But any memory allocated to a process is reclaimed when the process terminates.

Comment: This is a question about operating systems, not a programming language

Comment: Smart pointers aren't a "weird garbage collecting mechanism". Rather, they are a *clean* mechanism that doesn't produce any garbage!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Spoken like a true C++ zealot.

Comment: I'm a C zealot who has little kindness towards C++, and I still agree with Kerrek's claim. Smart pointers and RAII are vastly "cleaner" than garbage collection.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I didn't think there was anything emotional about this. The point is that both C and C++ are *deterministic* (unlike people who write programs in them, perhaps), and so there simply *is* no garbage. When you use the languages correctly, you always know what every piece of data is for and who is responsible for it.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Perhaps I overstated it a bit. I've seen the C++ folks get medieval over this point one time too often, I guess...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I wouldn't know... most C++ folks I've met are perfectly amicable people whose patience for explaining for the umpteenth time to random strangers why C++ doesn't really *need* a garbage collector (even though of course there exist several) far exceeds my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any memory you don't free will be automatically freed by the operating system when your program exits. This means it's generally safe to call `exit()` at any time, though you need to be careful about other resources that aren't automatically freed, like global atoms on Windows and named pipes and others.

Comment: By *most* operating systems. There's nothing in the C standard that says the the OS /must/ clean up after you.

Comment: Except when your program runs w/o operating system, is an operating system or is a kernel driver... :-)

Comment: @tangrs: Who gives an ice cream about what standard says in this regard? Be practical.

Answer (score 8):

When a process terminates, the OS removes the virtual memory which had been assigned to it.

Since the entirety of its address space goes away, so do all the objects within.

However, this is not the same as C++ garbage collection: no destructors get called. The memory just... quietly returns to the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

On virtually all platforms, all resources a process owns are recovered by the OS at process exit (certain kinds of shared resources, e.g., SYSV-IPC, not withstanding).

Answer (score 1):

Memory does not get garbage collected at all in C++, in that destructors won't be run, etc.  However, as part of cleaning up the process when the program exits, it will free any memory or other resources that were used by the program.  Other resources might be locks, shared memory, network connections, file handles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specified in C.

The C Standard says nothing about that but common OS deallocate the memory for you.